# Git checkout pathspec error. Command to get the correct path

Tags: git

**What am I trying to do:**

Replace a single local file (app.py) with the previously committed remote file.

**What have I tried:**

I can git add a file as follows:

```
git add app.py
git commit -m "added x "
git push -u sec_aggregator
```

But when I want to replace the local app.py on my pc with the remote one I tried this:

```
git fetch
git checkout sec_aggregator/feed/app.py
```

and got this error:

```
error: pathspec 'sec_aggregator/feed/app.py' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

How do you get the correct path please?

**Update:**

When I do the command `git branch`

I get this output:

```
  list
* master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a question.  You ran:

```
git add app.py
```

and apparently this worked (you show no error and the subsequent `git commit` seems to have succeeded as well).  So, should you now run:

```
git checkout sec_aggregator/feed/app.py
```

?  Or would it make more sense to run:

```
git checkout app.py
```

?  That is, why do you expect to use the *full* file name `sec_aggregator/feed/app.py` in `git checkout`, and the *partial* (relative to current directory) file name `app.py` in `git add`?  Have you navigated to a different directory / folder within your work-tree?

What you probably want here is:

```
git checkout <some-commit-specifier> -- app.py
```

since `git checkout` will use your current folder/directory within your work-tree to resolve the file's full name, the same way that `git add` does.  The *`some-commit-specifier`* part here may be as simple as `HEAD~1`.

**This might be all you need to make progress; if so, feel free to ignore the rest of this answer.** :-)  But this is not the only unusual thing in your question.  As [Julian noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57535885/1256452), you seem to be using the string `sec_aggregator` as the name of a *remote*.  This is a pretty unusual remote-name; most people have a repository with only one remote, named `origin`, and some have a repository in which they have added a second remote, typically called `upstream`.  It is possible to use pretty much any alphanumeric name as a remote, so `sec_aggregator` is OK here, but I suspect it's not what you mean to use.  (What was the exact output of this `git push` anyway?)

#### Long: about Git repositories, and working with them

So, let's take a look at what a Git repository *is*, and how different Git repositories talk to each other, because this all relates to your ultimate goal, which I'll repeat here:

> [I want to r]eplace a single local file (app.py) with the previously committed remote file.

Although there is a lot of extra machinery to make this all work, at its heart, a Git repository is a collection of *commits*.<sup>1</sup>  That is, Git doesn't store *files* but rather *commits*.  This collection is a sort of [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database), with the keys being commit hash IDs (which we will get to in a moment).  Each commit itself stores files—a full, complete snapshot of each file as of its state at the time you (or whoever) *made* the commit—so if you go down one level, into the commits, you *do* get files; but the storage-unit, as it were, is the commit.

The files stored in a commit are frozen for all time.  They can *never* be changed: not by you, nor by Git.  As you can imagine, re-freezing every file for every commit could use up a lot of storage space.  So Git *doesn't* actually do that.  Instead, each frozen file is in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed form.  I like to call this the *freeze-dried* format, although that's not a formal Git term.  That means they take less space, and sometimes a Git repository database is *smaller* than the files it stores.  But there's an even more useful trick here.  If the previous version of a file is frozen, and we need to make a *new* commit that has the *same version*, why not just re-use the freeze-dried copy of the file?  And that's exactly what Git does.  Commits keep re-using existing freeze-dried file copies, so that the growth of the `.git` directory holding the internal database is controlled.

So, each commit stores files—i.e., data—but that's not all.  A commit also stores some *metadata*, some information about the commit itself.  For instance, each commit has an *author* and a *committer*, usually the same person.  When you make a commit, you become the author-and-committer.  Each commit has a date-and-time-stamp too, or perhaps I should say two, as there's one for the author line and one for the committer line.  You also get to supply a *log message* giving a reason for the commit.  But there is one more key item in every commit, which Git calls the *parent*, or for merge commits, *parents*, plural.

Now, every commit acquires—at the point it comes into existence—a new and unique hash ID.  The hash ID is a big ugly string of letters and numbers that, technically, is the hexadecimal representation of a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of that commit.  One reason we can't know what the hash ID of a new commit *will be* until we've made it is that date-and-time-stamp part: if you make a commit, then remove it,<sup>2</sup> then make it again, the second one will have a different *time* in it and will actually be a different commit, with a different hash ID, *even if it stores all the same file contents*.

The hash ID is, in effect, the true name of a commit.  Crucially, *every Git in the universe* will agree that *that* hash ID—whatever it is—is *the one and only correct hash ID* for *that* particular commit: the one with that snapshot of those files, made by you, with your log message, on the date-and-time at which you made it.  So Git can use this hash ID as a unique key, in a key-value database, to store and retrieve this commit, and—importantly—your Git can call up another Git and ask it: *Do you have this hash ID?*  If they—the other Git—do have that hash ID, they have your commit.  If not, they don't.

In addition to all of this, your Git stores the hash ID of the *previous* commit—the one that goes before this commit—in the metadata for this commit.  So, given a commit, Git can look at its parent and get the hash ID of the previous commit.  Your Git can then retrieve *that* commit from its database of commits.  That commit has a snapshot of all of the files as of the time you (or whoever) made *that* commit, and it, too, has a parent hash ID, which locates yet another earlier commit, and so on.

This means that Git can start with the *most recent* or *last* commit, at the end of a long backwards-looking chain, and work back to the very first commit you (or whoever) made.  This very-first commit does not have any parent hash ID, simply because it *can't:* there was no earlier commit to connect back to.  Except for cases where your string of commits branches or merges—which I won't cover properly here—this means your Git repository structure is really simple:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, the uppercase letters stand in for the actual hash IDs of each commit.  We draw them as pointing to their *parent* commits.  Now Git just needs some way to remember the actual hash ID of the last commit, `H`, and that's where a *branch name* comes in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The branch name `master` holds the raw hash ID of commit `H`, so that `H` is the *last* commit on master.  To make a *new* commit, you modify some file, `git add` it, and run `git commit`.  The `git commit` gathers your log message—in this case, from your `-m` argument—and uses your name and email address and the current date-and-time to set up most of the metadata.  It uses hash ID of the *current commit* `H`—which is stored in the name `master`—as the *parent* for the new commit.  It freezes all the files into the new commit, which we'll call `I`.  Let's draw it in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Now that commit `I` exists, and has frozen-for-all-time copies of all of the files—a new snapshot—Git simply *changes the hash ID stored in the name `master`*, so that `master` now points to commit `I` instead of commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

Like each stored file's contents, the commit's contents can never be changed.<sup>3</sup>  All commits are permanent (mostly—see footnote 2) and read-only (totally).

---

<sup>1</sup>This extra machinery is deliberately exposed, in Git, so it's possible to (ab)use Git to store files directly, e.g., through the use of tags.  But that's not how it's designed to work.

<sup>2</sup>It's a little bit tricky to *remove* a commit, but it is possible.  Essentially, you have to make the commit un-find-able first.  This gets into the notion of *reachability* in a graph, which again we won't go into here, but see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) for more about this.

<sup>3</sup>The reason for this is that the hash IDs are cryptographic checksums *of* the contents.  Make any change, and what you have is a new and different internal object, with a new and different checksum.  The old object is still there in the database.  You didn't *change* a file, or a commit: you just made a *new* file, or a *new* commit.

---

#### Quick recap of the above

- Every commit has a unique hash ID.
- Each commit stores a frozen copy of all files forever (or as long as the commit itself continues to exist).
- Each commit has some set of *parent* hash IDs, usually just the one immediate parent.  (The very first commit has no parent.  A merge commit starts with the usual parent, but then has more; we won't get into the details here.)
- Nothing in any commit can ever be changed.
- A branch name like `master` simply identifies the *last* commit in the chain.  From here, Git can work backwards to earlier commits.
- So Git *finds* commits by starting with a name, like `master`, and working backwards.
- One Git repository can talk to another.  When it does so, it talks about what it has *by* hash ID.  The hash IDs are the universal exchange method.
- You, as a human, will generally use *names* like `master`.  But you can run `git log` or use other tricks to find the hash IDs, which may matter in a moment.

#### A brief-ish look at the index and work-tree

Commits, and their stored files, are frozen for all time.  That's great for archival, but useless for getting any *new* work done.  You need to be able to take all the files *out* of some commit, un-freezing and re-hydrating them.  Git therefore sets up a work area, which Git calls your *work-tree* or *working tree* or other variations along this line.  This folder, plus any sub-folders Git needs to create, holds the files extracted from the commit.  The files have full names, e.g., `feed/app.py`, such that your computer requires making the sub-folder `feed`.  These folders *aren't* stored in Git;<sup>4</sup> the files just have full names that force Git to create folders to hold them.

In any case, checking out some branch-and-commit, as in `git checkout master`, tells Git: *extract all the files from that commit, into my work-tree, so that I can see them and work with them.*  The *branch* is the argument you gave to `git checkout`, and the *commit* is based on the hash ID stored in the branch name.  In our drawings above, that was first commit `H`, then commit `I` after we made the new one.

As we saw above, to make a new commit, you can just work with the work-tree file—it's an ordinary file and you can do *anything* to it that your computer will let you do to it—and then run `git add` on it.  But why do you have to `git add` the file every time you change it?

This is where Git's *index* comes in.  The index or *staging area* (or sometimes, rarely these days, the *cache*) holds a copy of each file that `git checkout` checked out.  This copy is in the freeze-dried format, ready to go into the next commit.<sup>5</sup>  Initially, that's just the actual copy from the previous commit.  Running `git add` has Git compress / freeze-dry the *updated* contents and put those into the index.

What this means is that, at all times, the index holds copies of the files you propose to put into the *next* snapshot.<sup>6</sup>  Initially, the index matches the current commit.  You then change work-tree files, but the index still matches the current commit: nothing new is `staged for commit` yet.  Then you `git add` the file to *replace* the index copy with a freeze-dried version of the work-tree copy.  Now something *is* `staged for commit`.

In other words, at all times, you have *three* active copies of each file.  Let's consider the file `README.md` for a nice concrete example.  Note that the syntax with the colon in it is special to Git, i.e., `HEAD:README.md` and `:README.md` won't work with most commands on your computer.  But `git show`, and some other Git commands, use this `commit:path` syntax.  (Annoyingly, the colon means something *different* in `git fetch` and `git push`.)

- `HEAD:README.md` is the frozen copy in the current commit.  (Use `git show HEAD:README.md` to view it.)  You cannot change this one, but it's easy to access.
- `:README.md` is the frozen-*format* copy in the *staging area*, i.e., the index.  (Use `git show :README.md` to view it.)  You *can* change this one, by replacing it.  Use `git add` to replace it from the third copy, which is:
- `README.md` is an ordinary file in your work-tree.  Use ordinary commands to view it or change it or whatever.

In fact, *all* frozen copies in *every* commit are accessible at all times, but the one (or ones) in the *current commit* has (have) a special role.  This is in part because `HEAD` plays a big part in what `git status` says.

The `git status` command will tell you that some files are *staged for commit* and other files are *not staged for commit*.  To do that, `git status` runs two separate comparisons.  The first one is `HEAD`-vs-index.  The second one is index-vs-work-tree:

- First, for each file in `HEAD`, compare it to the one in the index.  Do they match?  If so, *say nothing*.  If not, say that this file is *staged for commit*.
- Next, for each file in the index, compare it to the one in the work-tree.  Do they match?  If so, *say nothing*.  If not, say that this file is *not staged for commit*.

There are some extra cases, e.g., files in your work-tree that aren't in your commit, or files that have been removed from your index and/or work-tree.  But the above is the heart of what `git status` tells you about the *next* commit you would make if you ran `git commit` right now—the *staged for commit* files—or the commit you *could* make if you ran more `git add` commands.

Crucially, your work-tree, and the index that sits between your work-tree and the Git repository, is *specific to this particular Git repository*.  When you have your Git call up some other Git, they will exchange *commits*.  Your index and your work-tree are private: they cannot see yours.  By the same token, *their* index, and their work-tree if they have one,<sup>7</sup> are also private.  You cannot see theirs.

---

<sup>4</sup>They sort of are, and sort of aren't.  The end result is mostly "aren't" as you cannot store an empty directory in Git.

<sup>5</sup>Technically, the *blob object* is actually already in the Git database.  The index just refers to that object by its hash ID.  When you `git add` an updated file, this will create a new blob object if needed, and the index will now refer to  the new blob object.  If the contents you `git add` match those of some stored version, anywhere in the repository, Git will re-use the existing blob object.

<sup>6</sup>The index takes on an expanded role during a conflicted merge.  It also has some other uses.  Saying *the index represents your next commit* is not *wrong*, but not really complete—but this answer is already long enough.

<sup>7</sup>If you use GitHub or Bitbucket or any other similar web hosting service, they have *bare* repositories that have no work-tree.  In order to `git push` to some server repository, that server repository is typically also created with `--bare`.  This sidesteps a bunch of problems that could occur if you want to update a branch that *they* have checked-out.  Without a work-tree, they cannot check out *any* branch.

---

#### Another quick recap

- The special name `HEAD` refers to both your *current branch* and your *current commit*.  (Git has two ways to ask about `HEAD`; one produces the branch name, the other produces the commit hash ID.)  While the commits themselves cannot be changed, you can select any branch name for `HEAD` and therefore change which commit is the *current* commit.  Adding a new commit automatically updates the branch name, so that the new commit you just made *is* the current commit now.
- The *index* or *staging area* holds every file that will go into your *next* commit.
- The *work-tree* is where you can see and work with your files.  Git doesn't really need this at all: Git's main concern is with the repository itself, and then with the index since that's the source of new commits.  But Git *has to* provide a work-tree, so that *you* can actually use Git.
- The work-tree and index are private to this Git repository.

#### Reframing your original problem

Note that as humans, we tend to be concerned with our work-tree files.  But Git isn't, not very much anyway.  This all comes back to the key problem with your desire:

> ... I want to replace the local app.py on my pc with the remote one ...

There *isn't a remote one*, as far as Git itself is concerned.  Your Git is going to call up another Git.  That other Git has *commits*.  Your Git either already has all of their commits, or will get any new ones from them if needed.  That's what `git fetch` does: your Git calls up their Git, asks their Git about *their* branches and tags and so on, and collects from them any new commits they have that you don't.  Once it has all their commits added to your database, `git fetch` is done and the two Gits stop talking to each other.

You may well already have all of their commits.  If so, there's no need to `git fetch` here at all.  That's probably the case above: you started with all of their commits, then you made one new commit and gave them that one via `git push`.  You still have all of their commits (and they now have all of yours too).

In any case, now that you have all of their commits, you can select any of those commits—which are all in *your* repository now—and either check out that entire commit, or selectively extract individual files from individual commits.  This is where `git checkout` gets quite messy.  Git 2.23 adds new commands that you can use instead of `git checkout`, to help keep this stuff straighter, but we'll just talk about `git checkout` and `git show` here.

Using `git checkout`, you can tell your Git:

- Extract one specific file from one specific commit.  Copy this file into the index, then copy it from the index to the work-tree.

Using `git show`, you can tell your Git:

- Find one specific file in one specific commit.  Show this file to the standard output: the terminal window, or wherever I have redirected it.

Note that this `git checkout` will overwrite your current index copy.  (You can fix or change this later if you want, using, e.g., `git reset`.)  The `git show` won't do this.

To achieve the first one, you must pick a commit.  The easiest way is often to use `git log` to find the hash ID, then cut-and-paste that ID with your mouse:

```
git checkout <hash-id> -- path/to/file
```

To achieve the second one, pick a commit again, and run:

```
git show <hash-id>:path/to/file
```

There's a bit of weirdness here.  With `git checkout`, the path to the file is *relative to where you are in the work-tree*, just as it is with `git add`.  If you're in the sub-folder `feed` and the file is named `feed/app.py`, you just use `app.py` here.  But with `git show`, you must use the *full name* of the file, *or* write `git show hash-id:./app.py`.  (Internally, this has to do with the fact that `git add` and `git checkout` take arguments that Git calls *pathspecs*, while `git show` doesn't.  But in practice it's just Git being messy and a bit hard to use.)

#### There are a lot of ways to name commits

As shown above, you can name a commit by its hash ID.  You can use `git log`, perhaps with `--all --decorate --online --graph`—one of my favorite Git commands—to find lots of hash IDs, which you can then cut and paste.  You can use a *branch name* like `master` to mean *the commit that the name points to*.  For instance, if your graph looks kind of like this (though `git log --graph` will draw it vertically instead of horizontally):

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- test
```

you can use the name `test` to mean *commit `L`*, just as the name `master` means commit `H`.  And, when you have a *remote* like `origin` and run `git fetch`, your Git sets up all your *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/master`, to remember what your Git got from their Git when your Git called them up and said: *Hey, what commits do you have, under what branch names?*

So, if you *had:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

and then you *added a new commit `I` to the end of your master*, you now have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master
```

So now instead of finding the actual hash ID for commit `H`, you can use the name `origin/master` to identify it.  Hence:

```
git show origin/master:feed/app.py
```

will let you see the version that is still in commit `H`, which is still identified by your `origin/master`.

Your `origin/master` will be *automatically updated* on each `git fetch` to `origin`: your Git calls up their Git, asks it what branches *they* have, and they say "I have `master` and it's commit *big-ugly-hash-ID*".  Your Git *gets* that commit if you don't have it yet—along with all the earlier commits you need too—and now you have it.  Then your Git sets *your* `origin/master` to remember that big ugly hash ID.

So, this gets us to the final, and maybe best, way to view or extract that file from their commit: run `git fetch` if needed, then use `git show` or `git checkout` with the *name* `origin/master`—assuming you call that other Git `origin`, as most people do—and the appropriate path name.  For `git checkout`, the appropriate path name depends where you are in your work-tree.  For `git show`, the appropriate path name is the full path or starts with `./`.  The syntax for `git checkout` is:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <path>
```

and the syntax for `git show` is:

```
git show <commit>:<path>
```

and you just have to remember that they're different like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for

```
git checkout sec_aggregator/feed app.py
```

This will checkout `app.py` from branch `feed` defined on remote 
`sec_aggregator`

Comment: Hi.  git branch is "* master"

Answer (score 0):

To replace a file with the previously committed version you can do:

```
git checkout add.py
```

or

```
git reset --hard add.py
```

Please make sure that you don't have unsaved changes for the `add.py` in the working directory before running any of them. Those operations are not working-directory safe, so your local changes for that file will be lost.